# how to get two string array item position and store in each separate string array in android

Tags: java, arrays

Sorry for my bad English. I am using two separate string array for each item of arraylist. All things working fine . My Question is I want to take each item of String array (say) if i take string array "asasaqty" and another item of string array "asasaId" then I want to store each item of string array value in third string array (say:[id1,qty1] and so on). Please let me know if there is a proper solution for this.

Below is my code.

Thanks in advance

```
String [] asasaqty;
    String [] asasaId;

    final AddToCartData addToCartData = response.body();
                    shoppingBagArrayList = addToCartData.getData();

                    asasaqty = new String[shoppingBagArrayList.size()];
                    asasaId = new String[shoppingBagArrayList.size()];


                    for (int i = 0; i < shoppingBagArrayList.size(); i++) {


                        asasaqty[i] = shoppingBagArrayList.get(i).getQty();

                     asasaId[i]=shoppingBagArrayList.get(i).getProductId();


                    System.out.println("==========wwwww========"+ Arrays.toString(asasaqty));
                    System.out.println("======wwwwssssswwwwss======"+ Arrays.toString(asasaId));

                   /* HashMap<String,String> map=new HashMap<String,String>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < asasaqty.length; i++) {
                   map.put(asasaqty[i],asasaId[i]);
                        System.out.println("======aaaaaaa======"+ map.put(asasaqty[i],asasaId[i]));

                    }*/
```

After printing the value in logcat the value is looking like

```
/System.out: ==========wwwww========[3, 2]
/System.out: ======wwwwssssswwwwss======[151, 10]
```

Now i want to take another String array and store each item asasaqty and asasaId in separate array like below

```
String[] xyz = [3,151] and 
String[] abc = [2,10]
```

Please let me know how can we do this.

Comment: You want to map first item of array1 to first item of array2 , and so on.. Is this what you want? Then use a hashmap.

Comment: I used it but it print the value separately please see my commented code.

Comment: Why are you putting items in the map inside println?

Comment: just for checking the values. Can u please let me know how to store it in string array.

Comment: Like @Ravi said, use a HashMap with asasaId as Key, and asasaqty as your value. You dont need 3 separate String arrays.

Comment: @Deepakkaku. please write the code  for more clarification for me please.

Comment: String[] xyz = [3,151] --> This is wrong. Having int in String array . Use it this way String[] xyz = ["3","151"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use productID and key (Assuming it is unique) and qty as value.

```
 HashMap<Integer,Integer> dataMap = new HashMap<>();

    for (int i=0; i <shoppingBagArrayList.size; i++){
        dataMap.put(shoppingBagArrayList.get(i).getProductId() , shoppingBagArrayList.get(i).getQty());
    }

    System.out.println("DataMap: "+dataMap);
```

Comment: he already has an arraylist shoppingBagArrayList which has both the values, Qty as well as ID. you dont need to create extra String arrays. 
just fetch from arraylist and populate the HashMap

Comment: omg how stupid i am ,sorry both of you sir. Everything is working fine you already said i am printing the wrong values. that's made me confused.Actually this is my first e-commerce project and i really nervous. Thank you guys . you save my lots of time . I upvote both of you.